# Clear OS-level cache

Tags: linux, cache, database, oracle

I have Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6 with Oracle 12c database. I am doing performance benchmarking but there seems to be an OS level cache causing only 1st time read to take significant time.

How can I tell what is being cached and is there a way to clear it?

Answer (score 1):

I’m on mobile so I cant provide sample output but

```
$ free -m
```

Will report cache

You can as root run

```
sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

To drop the cache